# proxy_pass isn't working when SELinux is enabled, why?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, selinux

I'm having an application listening on port 8081 and Nginx running on port 8080. The proxy pass statement looks like:

```
$ cat /var/etc/opt/lj/output/services/abc.servicemanager.conf

location /api/abc.servicemanager/1.0 { proxy_pass     http://localhost:8081;}
```

In `nginx.conf`, I include this file as:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/services/*.conf;
```

The `/etc/nginx/conf.d/service` is a symlink:

```
# ll /etc/nginx/conf.d/

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   39 Dec 10 00:19 services -> ../../../var/etc/opt/lj/output/services
```

This is a CentOS 7.0 SELinux Enabled system. If I `setenforce 0`, and make it Permissive, I don't see any issues. So the file is in right place and no issues with paths. If SELinux is enforcing, I see the following in audit log:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1418348761.372:100930): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=3936 comm="nginx" path="/var/etc/opt/lj/output/services/abc.servicemanager.conf" dev="xvda1" ino=11063393 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
```

I want to know how to enable Nginx to find the conf file without having to disable SELinux.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Read about audit2allow and used it to create a policy to allow access to the denied requests for Nginx.

Step 1 involves running `audit2allow` targeting nginxlocalconf:

```
$ sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | \
     grep denied | audit2allow -m nginxlocalconf > nginxlocalconf.te
```

Step 2, review results:

```
$ cat nginxlocalconf.te 

module nginxlocalconf 1.0;

require {
    type httpd_t;
    type var_t;
    type transproxy_port_t;
    class tcp_socket name_connect;
    class file { read getattr open };
}

#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'httpd_can_network_connect'
allow httpd_t transproxy_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
allow httpd_t var_t:file { read getattr open };
```

Review steps to activate:

```
$ sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep denied | \
   audit2allow -M nginxlocalconf
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i nginxlocalconf.pp
```

Step 3, active:

```
$ sudo semodule -i nginxlocalconf.pp
```

Comment: i follow this step by step and it works. great. but i have no idea what I did. wondering where i can learn more about this.

Answer (score 45):

Worth noting for beginners in SELinux that if your proxied service is running on 8080, you can use the command below without compiling a policy.

```
$ sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1 -P
```

Comment: Is it really about the port? I think SELinux was denying him access to the config file:  `... { getattr } .. path="......."...`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The OP's issue was file-system access issue, not the network connection. I should have commented on Vijay Shankar's answer.

Comment: This is really useful for people like me that gets here by Google!

Answer (score 6):

If you have another port or custom port allow it:

Show allow port in http:

```
semanage port -l | grep http
```

This is output in my localhost:

```
http_cache_port_t              tcp      8080, 8118, 8123, 10001-10010
http_cache_port_t              udp      3130
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
pegasus_http_port_t            tcp      5988
pegasus_https_port_t           tcp      5989
```

And allow 8081:

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8081
```

Comment: Is it really about the port? I think SELinux was denying him access to the config file:  `... { getattr } .. path="......."...`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Always prefer changing types to creating custom policies. In this case, Nginx will serve files with the `httpd_sys_content_t` type. Assuming your files are located in /var/www:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/*
restorecon -R -v /var/www
```