# Docker Nginx stopped: [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream

Tags: nginx, docker, amazon-ecs

I am running docker-nginx on ECS server. My nginx service is suddenly stopped because the `proxy_pass` of one of the servers got unreachable. The error is as follows:

```
[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "dev-example.io" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:988
```

My config file is as below:

```
 server {
       listen      80;
       server_name     test.com;
       location / {
          proxy_pass         http://dev-exapmle.io:5016/;
          proxy_redirect     off;

          ##proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

          client_max_body_size       10m;
          client_body_buffer_size    128k;

          proxy_connect_timeout      90;
          proxy_send_timeout         90;
          proxy_read_timeout         90;

          proxy_buffer_size          4k;
          proxy_buffers              4 32k;
          proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
          proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
       }
}

server {
   listen       80 default_server;
   server_name  localhost;

   #charset koi8-r;
   #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

   location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
   }

   #error_page  404              /404.html;

   # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
   #
   error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }
}
```

I have many servers in the config file, even if one server was down, I need to have running nginx. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: typically this can be for two reasons: either the service in http://dev-exapmle.io:5016/ is down or not responding to requests; or either you have some selinux configuration which is preventing nginx from proxying the requests. I'd look into the logs for for the app serving dev-example.io. If you don't see anything coming in, it's probably a selinux issue, in which case you may want to have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435655/nginx-proxy-pass-not-working-in-selinux

Comment: @JoséAntonioHaroPeralta thanks for the comment. yes that service, dev-exapmle.io:5016, is down. But I have many other services in my nginx config file that works but because of this service, the nginx stopped. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: include a resolver directive (pointing for example to google, 8.8.8.8). Nginx will resolve to that if it can't reach your site, as indicated in answers to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845674/setup-nginx-not-to-crash-if-host-in-upstream-is-not-found

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Include to prevent Nginx from crashing if your site is down, include a resolver directive, as follows:

```
 server {
       listen                80;
       server_name           test.com;
       location / {
          resolver           8.8.8.8;
          proxy_pass         http://dev-exapmle.io:5016/;
          proxy_redirect     off;
 ...
```

WARNING! Using a public DNS create a security risk in your backend since your DNS requests can be spoofed. If this is an issue, you should point the resolver to a secure DNS server.

Comment: Thanks. what if I use resolver 127.0.0.1  ? and if the server gets reachable again, would it routes the correct path?

Comment: Hi, presumably this just adds another DNS resolution endpoint. In my case, the DNS address had been deleted and would not be resolvable anywhere. Is there not a way to have nginx simply treat the page as down rather than crashing the entire instance?

Comment: For all copypasters like me ther is missing semicolon  resolver 8.8.8.8;

Answer (score 84):

Just adding a resolver did not resolve the issue in my case. But I was able to work around it by using a variable for the host.
Also, I guess it makes more sense to use Docker's DNS at 127.0.0.11 (this is a fixed IP).

Example:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.com;
  
  location / {
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    set $example dev-example.io:5016;
    proxy_pass http://$example;
  }
}
```

I found the variable workaround on [this page](https://sandro-keil.de/blog/let-nginx-start-if-upstream-host-is-unavailable-or-down/).

Comment: Correct syntax is:
    `set $example "dev-example.io:5016";`
    `proxy_pass http://$example;`

Comment: @jozo
Doesn't help, returns 502 in my setup.

Comment: Works well. In the case of using Docker:
1) `echo "resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=60s;" > ./conf.d/resolvers.conf` 2) docker-compose.yml: `volumes: - ./conf.d/resolvers.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/resolvers.conf`

Comment: but how to deal upstream node ???

Answer (score 3):

This usually means that the dns name you provided as upstream server cannot be resolved. To test it, log on nginx server and try pinging upstream server provided and see if the name resolution completes correctly, If its a docker container try `docker exec -it` to get a shell, then try pinging the upstream to test the name resolution. If the contianer is stopped try  to use IP address instead of dns name in your server block.

```
proxy_pass         http://<IP ADDRESS>:5016/;
```

You can also use the resolver directive if you want to use different dns server for this location than the host system:

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
```

Comment: There is no IP address for that, I have dns which is end-url of Docker-Cloud services

Comment: Bring up a default config nginx container, then try pinging the dns to see if the resolution happens correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Then I use resolver instead. but if I use resolver 127.0.0.1; would it work fine as well? What will happen if the DNS gets to work later? Also doesn't it need to have valid=30s; ?

Comment: resolver 127.0.0.1 means you are running a dns server on localhost, are you?  when the dns server is fixed remove the resolver line. valid 30s means do not requery for 30s use the existing value.

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it automatically? Use resolver when it's down, use the DNS when it's up again. It could be done automatically only using a script?

Comment: You can script it to check every 5 seconds for example and change the config accordingly

Comment: @Farhad Farahi, will setting "resolver 8.8.8.8;" work if I already have "nameserver 8.8.8.8" in my /etc/resolve.conf?

Comment: @RicoChen this should override your `/etc/resolvce.conf` for nginx process and workers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with:

```
    location /radio/antena/ {
        proxy_pass http://antenaradio.rs:4550;
    }
```

Including a variable with the `resolver` directive solves everything:

```
    location /radio/antena/ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        set $my_stream_1 antenaradio.rs:4550;
        proxy_pass http://$my_stream_1;
    }
```

By the way, my server is NGINX/1.23.2, running on Android ARMv7 :)

Answer (score 0):

When using nginx plus, you can get around this as well by adding a zone to your upstream with resolve. When use this test in your proxypass. When the server some-server starts resolving, it will starting pass traffic to it.

Make sure to as stated above, put a resolver in other parts of your config. For docker, I use
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=1s;

```
upstream test {
        zone test-zone 64k;
        server some-server:1234 resolve;
}
```

As an alternative, you may want to check out [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy), which can automatically determine the upstream docker containers for the reverse proxy. It generate its configuration file on the fly as containers start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

Upstream not found means that the domain name could not be resolved locally.

Add an upstream configuration to your config file. There is no need for a resolver, you can provide the IP directly.

```
upstream dev-example.io {

    server 127.0.0.1:5016;
}
```